# Node.js MongoDB updateOne not working as desired

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Please help me fix my code.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
var a = "2018";
var b = "December";
var c = "12";
var d = "28";
MongoClient.connect(url,{ useNewUrlParser: true },(err, client) => {
    if (err){
  return console.log('Unable to login to Mongo DB');
}
console.log('Connected to Mongo DB');
const db = client.db('test');
db.collection('updateTest').updateOne({_id:a},{$addToSet:{"b.c":{
    "temp":d
}}},{upsert:true},(err,result) =>{
    if(err){
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});
client.close();
});
```

The problem here is with this piece of code ({_id:a},{$addToSet:{"b.c":

_id takes the value of a as defined above with no problem but I'm unable to pass values assigned to b and c resulting in a undesired object names.

The intent here is to pass ({_id:"2018"},{$addToSet:{"December.12":

tried ways known to me but neither worked

```
{$addToSet:{`${b}.${c}`:

var e = `${b}.${c}`;

{$addToSet:{e:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [computed object property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) to achieve the goal:

```
db.collection('updateTest').updateOne({_id:a},{$addToSet:{[`${b}.${c}]:{
    "temp":d
}}},{upsert:true},(err,result) =>{
    if(err){
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});
client.close();
});
```